# How to "click" on certain proposal from autosuggestion on Amazon using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, autosuggest

I am trying to automate auto complete suggestions on amazon.com. But unlike google search options, xpath of suggestions is always changing. The code I posted doesn't work every time because sometimes the xpath/id/cssselector of the desired suggestion is changing (@id=\"issDiv8\"] sometimes it is "issDiv4" or "issDiv6" and so on.

[image]

```
WebElement searchTextField = driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));

searchTextField.sendKeys("turbo");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"issDiv8\"]")));
List<WebElement> autoSuggest = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"issDiv8\"]"));


System.out.println("Auto Suggest List ::" + autoSuggest.size());
for (int i = 0; i < autoSuggest.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(autoSuggest.get(i).getText());
    if (autoSuggest.get(i).getText().equals("turbotax")) {
        autoSuggest.get(i).click();
        System.out.println("Success");

        break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid using third party services to show images. If you need to add images, add them to the post by either clicking the image button while editing, or copying the image and clicking CTRL+V, or in any other way pasting it) directly into the post. Third party image services [can break at any time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354950/6296561), and either leave a dead link, or the URLs can be used for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebdriverWait` to handle dynamic element and use the following `xpath`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@data-keyword='turbotax']")));
element.click()
```

Comment: I have almost the same question about "quantity" when I try to buy something. Should I make new topic or I can ask here ?

Comment: @Alex : That should be different question.This is the solution of a particular problem and can be use by future reader.If you asked multiple questions on a single post OP might confuse to see this answer.Thanks.